# arrays, booleans and logical thinking

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

Question in book:

It is a well-researched fact that men in a restroom generally prefer to maximize their distance from already occupied stalls, by occupying the middle of the longest sequence of unoccupied places.

For example, consider the situation where ten stalls are empty. _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

The first visitor will occupy a middle position:
_ _ _ _ _ _ X _ _ _ 
The next visitor will be in the middle of the empty area at the left.
_ _ X _ _ X _ _ _ _
```

Write a program that reads the number of stalls and then prints out diagrams in the format given above when the stalls become filled, one at a time. Hint: Use an array of boolean values to indicate whether a stall is occupied.

I am struggling in programming this question and I'm confused on how to apply the booleans, and how to do the problem in general. I have this code written but I don't think it makes any sense,
Help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Stall 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 

        Random random = new Random();

        String[] array = {"_"," _ "," _ "," _ "," _ "," _ "," _ "," _ "," _ "," _"};



        boolean filled = true; // Checking to see if stalls are completely filled

        while (filled = true)  
        {
            for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0 ; i--)
            {
              String number = array[i];
              if (!(number.equals("X")))    //  if filled,all stalls would be marked as X
                {

                     filled = false;
                }
            }
        }

        boolean found = false;    //checking if "X" is found 

        while (filled = false)
        {

            while (found = false) // if not found generate a new number for array and set it to "X";
            {
                int  number1 = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
                if (!(array[number1].equals("X")))
                {
                    array[number1] = "X";
                    found = true;
                }
            }   
            while (found = true)                
            {
                int number2 = random.nextInt(10) + 1;

                for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                {
                    if (!(array[i].equals("X")))
                    {
                        array[number2] = "X";
                        found = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Help with what? Learn to use a debugger and follow what your code does.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Why does this make me thing of homework.... kalispera!

Comment: @meewoK It does come from a book! Na eisai kala!

Comment: The hint suggests representing `_ _ _ _ _ _ X _ _ _` as `[ false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false ]`.

Comment: FYI, `filled = true` is using the assignment operator, which won't do what you want. Use `while (filled)` instead (and `while (!filled)` for when it should be false). You should also actually use an array of booleans and not an array of strings - it will make your life easier.

Comment: in for loop you should add index number to array if it was unoccupied, once while loop is over you can display logic.

Comment: if (!(number.equals("X")))    {

          filled = false;

} else { foundArryalist.add(i);}

Answer (score -1):

Your code has enough problems that it's hard to correct it without completely rewriting it.

Some suggestions though,
Use a boolean array to represent the stalls like your teacher suggested, not a String array as you have now.

Lines like this:

```
while (found = false)
```

are not working the way you think they are. Remember that one equals sign (=) sets variables values, while two (==) compares values. You'll want to be using == in a while loop 99% of the time.

Try to take time with your code and think over your method before you start. Always ask yourself, what is the most straightforward approach?